# Identifying and modifying list-column cells in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I used pivot_wider to spread my data.  However, there were duplicate rows (although I'm still not clear why), so the duplicates were stored in "list_columns." I'm now trying to identify which cells have been stored as lists, and I'd like to replace those values with just the first element in the list.

Example:

```
df <- tibble(
    a = list(c("a", "b"), "c"),
    b = list(1, 2),
    c = c(11, 22)
)
```

When I view this df in RStudio `View(df)` the first cell in the `a` column shows up as `c("a", "b")` (see screenshot).  [image]

I'm trying to identify the cells in my data.frame that are stored in that `c()` form, and then I want to replace those values with just the first element in the list.  I've tried is.vector(), is.list(), but I can't seem to figure out what the actual class type is of the values stored in that way, or how to operate on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `mutate/across` and `map/unnest`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.list), ~ map(., first))) %>% 
    unnest()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  a         b     c
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1    11
#2 c         2    22
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate_all(~ unlist(.)[1])

  a         b     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1    11
2 c         2    22
```

Or with the addition of `purrr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(~ unlist(map(., `[`, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Do you mind explaining the syntax of the map function?  What does the `[` parameter do?  I assume the "1" corresponds to the first index?

Answer (score 1):

Using the new `across` function from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~unlist(map(.x, `[`, 1))))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   a         b     c
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1    11
# 2 c         2    22
```